# Does this distance/metric/property have a name?

Tags: combinatorics, metric-spaces

I want to find the "similarity" between two lists of numbers (of the same length).

> e.g. A = (1, 7, 4, 3, 4), B = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>
> I want to find the smallest possible distance between elements in the sets
>
> I re-order A and B to get: A = (1, 3, 4, 4, 7), B = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>
> Then take the difference: (∣1-1∣=0, ∣3-2∣=1, ∣4-3∣=1, ∣4-4∣=0, ∣7-5∣=2) --> 0+1+1+0+2=4 --> similarity is 4

Note that the easiest way to find this "smallest distance" is to order the numbers within each list. However, an alternative/equivalent calculation would have been to list all possible permutations, taken the difference of each, and then selected the smallest.

Is there a formal name for this property?

---

Related question, which discusses computational methods for extending a similar distance/measure to tuples: [Optimize pairings of two types of points with respect to the maximum distance inside any pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3867185/optimize-pairings-of-two-types-of-points-with-respect-to-the-maximum-distance-in) . Obviously this doesn't specify if the distance is euclidean, taxicab, or similar, but it does explore the idea of the minimum distance between two collections of points, which is the idea I'm interested in.

Comment: This is the taxicab metric. Note that if you calculated $B-A$ instead of $A-B$ you'd require the absolute value signs.

Comment: The taxicab distance. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Comment: I don't think it is the taxicab distance (although maybe it is just wearing a very fine disguise!). I've re-worded the question to try and make it clearer.

Comment: @MikeEarnest that is absolutely the intent. I've edited the question to try to make it clearer.

Comment: I do not think there is a name for it. The version where you allow permutations seems more reasonable, but computationally hard (probably NP). So you can name it as you want. Call it "Al", for example.